# Show the closed ball contains all of it's boundary points

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have seen and understand the proof of showing that the closed ball is a closed set by showing that the complement is open but is it possible to show that the closed ball is closed by showing it contains all of its boundary points?

Here is what I have so far:
Let (X,d) be a metric space

Let $\bar B_\epsilon$(x):= {y$\in$ X| d(x,y)$\le$$\epsilon$}

If z $\in$ X is a boundary point of $\bar B$$_\epsilon$(x), then  $B$$_\delta$(z)$\cap$$\bar B$$_\epsilon$(x)$\neq$$\varnothing$

Because the intersection is nonempty, then $\exists$y $\in$$B$$_\delta$(z)$\cap$$\bar B$$_\epsilon$(x)$

Therefore, d(y,z) < $\delta$ and d(y,x) $\le$ $\epsilon$

Here is where I made a jump in logic,

since y is in the closed ball as well as the ball around z, d(y,x)$\le$$\epsilon$ - $\frac{\delta}{2}$

as well as d(y,z)<$\frac{\delta}{2}$ because z is a boundary point so we can shrink $\delta$ to be arbitrarily small.

So by the triangle inequality, d(x,z) $\le$ d(x,y) + d(y,z) $\le$ ($\epsilon$ - $\frac{\delta}{2}$) + ($\frac{\delta}{2}$) = $\epsilon$

Since d(x,z)$\le$ $\epsilon$, z $\in$ $\bar B_\epsilon$(x)
Since z was an arbitrary boundary point of  $\bar B_\epsilon$(x), it contains all of its boundary points and is therefore a closed set.

Does this proof make sense?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is a bit fuzzy. You start with (what seems to be) a fixed $\delta >0$. Then you say it can be made arbitrarily small. But then we're dealing with a seemingly particular $\delta$ again.

Also, here's a quicker argument: show that the closed ball is closed. Show that any closed set contains all its boundary points.

Comment: If I were to remove the statement that I can shrink $\delta$ to be arbitrarily small and just use d(y,x) $\le$ $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ and then use the triangle inequality, all while keeping $\delta$ fixed would that make the argument sound ?

Comment: You can't make $\delta$ arbitrarily small while also keeping it fixed. That's two different things.

Comment: I am confused by your suggestion. I am trying to show that it is closed by showing it contains all of its boundary points by considering an arbitrary boundary point

Comment: I am removing the assumption that I am making $\delta$ small. I am keeping it fixed and choosing a y that satisfies the inequalities I mentioned in the comment

Comment: My last comment refers to the fact that the argument "make $\delta$ arbitrarily small [...] while keeping $\delta$ fixed" cannot be made sound (without substantial modifications), because you can't shrink a number if it is fixed.

Comment: I completely agree with that. I cannot shrink a number if it is fixed. So if I were to fix $\delta$ and never state that I can shrink it, while also picking a y$\in$X such that d(y,x) $\le$ $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ and d(y,z) < $\delta$, would the triangle inequality take care of the proof?